# Recursive sum of monotonic path areas

Tags: c, recursion, path, area

I am trying to come up with a recursive way to find the sum of all the areas of all monotonic paths from the upper left corner of a nxn grid to the lower right corner (each step of the path can either go right or down along the lines).

Assuming that the lower left corner has coordinates (0,0), I have the following function:

```
int sum(int current_sum, int x, int y, int n){
    if (x == n || y == 0)  
        return current_sum;

    return (sum(current_sum+y, x+1, y, n) + sum(current_sum, x, y-1, n));
}
```

, stopping when it reaches either the right side of the grid or the bottom line (any move from there won't change the current value of the area) and considering the sum of the areas resulting from moving right or down. The result is larger than it should be, and I'm having some trouble figuring out why. Could anyone have a look at it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think adding a concrete example with input, expected and actual output would help a lot.

Comment: This is a problem from Project Euler: https://projecteuler.net/problem=15

Comment: focus on return. x+1, y-1. how about using 2 step for loop with, x moves from low to high, y moves from high to low?  It could work-around the moving to zero-value wall.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer

Answer (score 1):

**Reading again, OP's solution seems to be correct already. My answer below for reference.**

---

This seems to be Project Euler [problem 15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15), or a very similar problem.

So if I understand correctly what you want to do is this:

1. Follow each path exactly once.
2. Count each distinct path and add the area under that path to the sum.

Doing this in a recursive fashion would look like this:

```
int area(int x, int y)
{
  if (x == 0 || y == 0)
    /* We are at the end of a path, terminate */
    return 0;

  /* We are not at the end, add the two choices possible from here */
  return area(x, y - 1) + area(x - 1, y) + y;
}
```

You will have to draw a figure to see that the last expression is correct. We only add y to the sum when we are moving right in the grid (-x), thus covering a column under us. Moving down (-y) does not cover any area.

This solution should be correct but it will be very slow. To speed it up, you can add *memoisation* which means saving the intermediate results of area(x, y) to a table and looking it up instead of calculating it each time. I will not write that solution for you but it is not hard to do. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> [..] from the upper left corner of a nxn grid to the *lower right corner* [..]

Your code does not reflect that:

```
// ...
  if (x == n || y == 0)  
    return current_sum;
// ...
```

Think of a path going completely horizontal. For example in a 2 on 3 grid, when indices start off with `0` and the lower left corner is `(0 | 0)`, then the lower right corner would be `(1 | 0)`. Now consider the *upper* right corner, which is `(1 | 2)`. Neither of the above conditions is true for these values, so you sum up the recursive calls of the two next cells: `(2 | 2)` (going right) and `(1 | 1)` (going downwards).

The first cell (going right) is the issue: There, `x == 2 == n` and thus you return the sum of the path *although* it's not ending in the lower right corner. Therefore, you sum too many paths, resulting in a too large overall sum.

---

I think this should do it:

```
unsigned sum_inner(
    unsigned const accumulatedSum,
    size_t const x, size_t const y,
    size_t const gridSideSize) {
  bool atRightEdge = (x == gridSideSize - 1);
  bool atBottomEdge = (y == 0);
  if (atRightEdge && atBottomEdge) {
    // Awesome, in lower right corner, so everything is fine
    // Except that with the implementation of the other two edge cases, this
    // will never be run (except for the 1x1 case)!
    printf("reached lower right edge!\n");
    return accumulatedSum + 1;
  } else if (atRightEdge) {
    // Right edge, so from here one can only go down. Since there's only one
    // possible path left, sum it directly:
    return accumulatedSum + y + 1;
  } else if (atBottomEdge) {
    // Bottom edge, so from here one can only go right. Since there's only one
    // possible path left, sum it directly:
    return accumulatedSum + (gridSideSize - x) + 1;
  } else {
    // Somewhere in the grid, recursion time!
    return sum_inner(accumulatedSum + y, x + 1, y, gridSideSize) +
           sum_inner(accumulatedSum, x, y - 1, gridSideSize);
  }
}

unsigned sum_monotonic_tl_br(size_t const gridSideSize) {
  return sum_inner(0, 0, gridSideSize - 1, gridSideSize);
}
```

[(Live with sizes from 1 to 15)](http://ideone.com/Wes17H)